# Mongo aggregation framework support in Morphia

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, morphia, aggregation-framework

I've looked through what scant documentation there is and the commit history on github and couldn't find any clues on whether the aggregation framework is supported in the latest version of Morphia.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: if you can run db.runCommand then you can execute aggregation framework query.  db.runCommand({"aggregate":"collectionName", "pipeline": [ <pipeline here> ] });

Answer (score 1):

Support for the aggregation framework is implemented and due to be released with version 0.108:
https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/449